# Can't carry out ng serve in VISUAL STUDIO CODE, angular cli

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

[image]

Why is ng term in yellow colour and why can't I ng serve, please assist.

Comment: Try doing `npm install -g @angular/cli` then run `ng serve`.

Comment: In addition to the comment above, verify that nodejs is installed too.